# How to call similar words in two languages with different meanings?

Tags: choix-de-mot, linguistique, noms

“Réel” happens be to an example of the kind of word, I have in mind. It looks like, and is sometimes translated (incorrectly) as “real” in English.

In some instances, that may be ok, for example “*en temps réel*” = “in real time”.

But my understanding is that it would be wrong to use “*réellement*” in the sense of “really”. A better translation would be “*vraiment*”.

What is the French term for this kind of word?

Comment: For questions concerning English translations, check this site : http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @zejam: I edited the question to ask for the FRENCH term, But your point is well taken.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're referring to a [false friend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend) or *[faux-ami](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faux-ami)*  in French, where a similar word has very different meaning in two different languages.

*“En temps réel”* is a proper translation for “in real time”; *“vraiment”* would be the translation of “really” rather than *“réellement”*.

Comment: I'm nearly disappointed that _faux-ami_ is **not** a false friend itself

Comment: So noted, and corrected. Thanks.